# Using Quasar as Nuxt(VUE) plugin - but icon-set isn't showing on QBtn (icon="mail"), how can correct it?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, quasar

I use:

*plugins/quasar.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import "quasar/dist/quasar.css";

import Quasar, { QBtn } from "quasar";
Vue.use(Quasar, { components: [QBtn] });
```

*pages/index.vue*

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <q-btn color="primary" icon="mail" label="On Left" />
  </div>
</template>
```

on clear Nuxt+Quasar ($ npm install --save quasar) installation

QBtn is working fine, but icon is not showing.

I try many config-tricks like https://quasar.dev/options/quasar-icon-sets#Vue-CLI-Way && https://quasar.dev/options/quasar-icon-sets#Quasar-CLI-Way - not working.

What can I do with it.

Thank you!

//When I install Quasar as stand-alone framework ($ quasar create ) - icon-set is showing fine even without any configuration.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar issue. Did you find a solution?